# Run host machine program from python docker

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

Actually, I have a little python server (using fastapi but it's not important) that start a program like that:

```
@app.put("/start_simulation/")
async def start_simulation():
try:
    Process = subprocess.Popen("Aimsun_Next.exe")
except Exception as e:
    raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Simulation process failed")
```

I put my little server in a python docker like that:

```
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /code
COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
COPY ./app /code/app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r ./requirements.txt
WORKDIR /code/app
CMD ["uvicorn", "server_main:app", "--reload", "--proxy-headers", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

and it seems to work fine!

But when the request "start_simulation" is called, it don't work because we are now in a docker.

PS: My "put" query doesn't look good but I shortened it to have a simple example

I would like my server in my docker have access to the path of my host machine to call the command "Aimsun_Next.exe". It's possible ?

Comment: You should think about a container as a different machine. So if you want to start a program on your host from a different machine, how would you do that?

Comment: There are multiple possibilities. I can set up a small server on my host machine and communicate with an http request, but it's kind of the same as keeping my fastapi server on my host machine.
Like @0x0fba say it, I can mount a volume and try to call my program but I have a little application and it's like to take a machin gun to kill a mosquito.

If there are no "simple solution" like using "magic docker command" to run command on my host machine, I think I will just use my server like that, on host machine or install it on an other machine without using docker

Comment: The whole point of running a program in an isolated Docker container is that the program in the container can't affect the host.  While you can work around a couple of the other similar cases, I think running a host program is actually impossible.

Comment: Please include code in the question as text rather than linking to external images. This makes it possible to search and easily copy the code in question to testi tout. Additionally it's way more accessible for people who use a screenreader.

Answer (score 2):

In your dockerfile you should indicate that you want to expose  the FastAPI port. Something like `EXPOSE 8000`. See [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose).
When you start the container you have to publish the port to localhost `docker run -p 8000:8080`.

It's possible to access a file on your local filesystem from your container, by "mounting" a volume. See [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume).
But I'm not sure you can launch it and if I wouldn't recommend it at all.

The idea behind containerization is that a container can run everywhere and is secure as it's isolated from whatever underlying OS.
Your container is an isolated environment. Furthermore the `python3.9` image is based on a specific Linux version and hasn't to ensure any kind of compatibility with whatever OS is used on the host.